# DIfference between IE and FF. Colors

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have found the difference in IE7 and FF in the following CSS code:

```
.list-common-wrapper .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled] .button-background, #id-chart-editor-active-event .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled] .button-background, .three-lists .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled] .button-background {
    background: url("../images/button/btn_var_bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left -120px transparent;
    color: #777777;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}
list.css (line 122)
.list-common-wrapper .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal .button-background, #id-chart-editor-active-event .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal .button-background, #id-profile-editor-move-attributes-buttons .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal .button-background {
    color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
}
list.css (line 132)
.button-unfixed-normal .button-background {
    background: url("../images/button/btn_var_bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 8px 4px 12px;
}
button.css (line 111)
Inherited froma.button-unfixed-def #
.list-common-wrapper .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled], #id-chart-editor-active-event .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled], #id-profile-editor-move-attributes-buttons .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled] {
    color: #777777;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}
list.css (line 142)
.list-common-wrapper .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-def {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 130%;
}
list.css (line 163)
.button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
button.css (line 104)
.button-unfixed .button-unfixed-def {
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 130%;
}
button.css (line 93)
a {
    color: #175DB5;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

It shows that the color #777777 is displayed differently in IE7 and FF (look at the arrow):

[image]

Comment: Are you viewing this on a Mac/PC?

Comment: My environment:

Windows 7
Internet Explorer 7

Answer (score 1):

You probably see a difference because of background image attached.

In case with IE7 - it simply does NOT support shorthand property for background.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

This needs to be changed

```
background: url("../images/button/btn_var_bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left -120px transparent;
```

to:

```
background-image: url('../images/button/btn_var_bg.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
...and so on....
```

Comment: Can the attribute 'disabled' affect the styling of the button for IE7? As it seems for me that this is the problem

Comment: This is not related to the topic. You need to accept this answer (if it fixed your issues) and start a new topic. Yes, 'disabled' property will change your styling.

Comment: Without you providing an HTML code (or better URL), we cannot help you. We can only imagine.

Comment: Sorry, mate. Just found a solution. It seems that IE7 has its own styling for the attribute `disabled`, so the problem is solved.

Your answer is good, anyway